# Create token from C# to php

Tags: c#, php, token

How to create token from C# (windows form) to php?

For example: send user id for deleting user from database

Website URL: `www.domain.com/delete.php?id={ID FROM C# WINDOWS FORM)`

So how to create token with C# and check token in php; if correct token, delete user from database?

php code:

```
$ids = JRequest::getVar('data');
        $ids_new = substr($ids, 0, -1);
        $db = JFactory::getDBO();
        $query = $db->setQuery("DELETE FROM #__users WHERE p_id IN(".$ids_new.");");
        if($db->query()){
            echo "1";
        }else{
            echo "0";
        }
```

Comment: we need more information , show us delete.php and tell us what kind of id exactly you want ( a db id , MD5, HASh, base64 etc..)

Comment: edited question , i want create token in C# FORM when anybody can't run delete url

Comment: Your edit still gives absolutely no insight into what you think a "token" is.

Comment: You seem to not understand what "token" means. You don't let your client generate a token, as then every client could do so - including malicious ones. You generate and store the token on the server, then send it to the client which can use it for a one-time operation or for a certain session.